# Facebook script all.js crashes in Chromium browser: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier all.js:57

Tags: javascript, facebook, syntax

I use the following code to initialize Facebook. After I changed many many things in a separate Javascript file that is loaded by the HTML page, I get an Uncaught Syntax Error inside the Facebook script (which is embedded in the HTML page in the following form), but I do not know the reason for this error and what causes it.

```
fbAsyncInitDone = false;
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId  : '{{app_id}}',
        status : true, // check login status
        cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
    });
    //fillinFriends();
    fbAsyncInitDone = true;
};

(function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }(document));
```

How can I make all.js work again? I think this error is related to Chromium, because Firefox still works. I badly need a working Facebook Javascript, because it is used by several Facebook elements on the page.

Comment: Welcome to Facebook development, where they randomly break stuff all the time. This sort of thing is fairly common and generally resolves itself in an hour or two. You can report it at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/ though.

Comment: First I thought it might be a pure FB bug, because it was listed on the Facebook developer's site. But I forgot to mention: I then re-deployed the previous code, which is completely different (Javascript file with more than 7500 lines), it works again in Chromium.